# Subreddit content using an R package as interfase to Pushshift

Tags: r, reddit

I'm using the `redditr` R package to retrive content rom Reddit and works fine for example:

```
devtools::install_github("geoffwlamb/redditr")
# load redditr
library(redditr)
# get 500 most recent reddit comments avilable from api
recent_comments <- get_reddit_content()
```

But when looking into the details of what I retrieve, I think there are missing data, for example the following post

https://www.reddit.com/r/disability/comments/ebk7bg/about_applying_for_disability_benefits/

is retrieved using this query

```
 many_recent_comments <- get_reddit_content(
      content_type = "submission", 
      subreddit = "disability",
      after = date_to_api("2019-12-14 23:59:59", tz = "EST"),
      before = date_to_api("2019-12-17 00:00:00", tz = "EST"),
author = "mkwildeman"
    )
```

But it retrieves only the title, not the text of the post, and it does not retrieve the "Question" label, it should be (I think) in the link_flair_body field but it is retrieved with a null value for this post, it should be "Question".

Is there an R package to retrieve all posts and the corresponding comments in order? I also tried to use this one but couln't. So I decided to retrieve only posts without comments but I'm getting only the title of the posts without the text, as shown using the code above.